# how to calculate arc length of the arc consisting of 3D points in opencv using python?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a curve sampled using discrete points. 
  It is not a closed curve.
  I want to calculate the arc length.
  In opencv the arclength function takes 2D points.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that taking discrete points this will be an estimate, but a rough method to calculate the arc length is to simply sum the [distances/magnitudes](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#magnitude) between subsequent points. So if `x` is the ordered list of sampled 2D points on the closed curve:

```
sum( magnitude(x[i]-x[i+1]) for i in range(len(points)-1) )
```

*If you know some other properties about the curve, you may be able to calculate this more accurately...*

.

The same technique can be applied to vectors of higher dimension, where you can use the generalised formula:

```
def dist(X,Y):
    return math.sqrt(
                     sum( (X[i] - Y[i])**2 for i in len(range(X)) )
                    )

sum( dist(x[i],x[i+1]) for i in range(len(points)-1) )
```

Comment: @Shan I was mistaken, `magnitude` only works for 2D vectors, so you need to generalise - I've updated my answer to incorporate this.